# AttributeError: module has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

When I try to change function name "random_string" which is used in auth_code (variable in model class) to any other name it shows me the error in the command line: AttributeError: module 'users_data.models' has no attribute 'random_string'

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
import random
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def random_string():
    return int(random.randint(000000, 999999))


def validate_phone_number(phone):
    if len(phone) < 7:
        raise ValidationError('Phone number can not be less than 7 digits')


class Users(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone', max_length=20, validators= 
                            [validate_phone_number])
    auth_code = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Code', 
                                    default=random_string)
    get_in_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=False, 
                                       editable=False)
```

I have seen many posts which cover my problem but I didn't find any useful. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: if you want use random_string function from users_data, you can make random_string function be users_data class function

Comment: just put random_string function in users_data class, maybe you can make random_string be a static method

Comment: I tried your advice. It didn't help me, unfortunately.

Comment: would you give your code?

Comment: https://paste.pics/edit/79f515e3a9603ff5b25cce2cc2de50b8

Comment: how about default=Users.random_string

Comment: https://paste.pics/edit/bf0982e1dbcf892b9c5b4b252b9d666d

Comment: According https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528807/built-in-callable-as-a-default-argument-for-a-django-field, your first code should be correct.. i think the problem doesnt from your example code

Comment: use your first code and would you to show error in command line?

Comment: First code isn't working for me. I provided the screenshot

Comment: how if you migrate? makemigrations and then migrate

Comment: See? I tried to use another name for the function and I got the error. https://paste.pics/edit/0b1ab61e2c68094053c0d97ca4dfa410

Comment: It's doesn't allow me to makemigrations and then migrate, cause is poping out error.

Comment: ctrl+c, stop server and then makemigrations, migrate how if this? im sorry for my capabilities in help you.. and dont forget to save your file

Comment: I did it man, same error.

Comment: how if you go back to first migrate if there is not any data in your db.. and then 
manage.py migrate my_app zero, you can migrate again your apps

Comment: You mean delete all migrations and then migrate again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123477/how-to-revert-the-last-migration, this will be help

Comment: Kinda scared, but I’ll try

Comment: Hahaha, sorry,,, i also just learn django too

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies within your migrations files, as shown in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826180/django-rename-default-function-on-model). Basically, when you generated your previous migration files, it was written that the default was value for a field was `random_string`.

Now, if you change that function name, your current code will work, but because your already-generated migration files use this function, they will raise an error as they cannot find that function anymore.

I dont know if simply updating the files to replace the name within them would be enough. Other solutions would be to reset the migrations (though it might come as a cost).

The link I've provided offers a script to fix that, but I haven't tested it myself